# MVC3 Meta tag Dynamically change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3, I am using Razor engine i have a layout.cshtml page which contains meta tag like

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/" />
```

I have some content pages like  abc.cshtml which has Layout.cshtml page as there's layout,so they are getting meta tags from layout.cshtml,i want that abc.cshtml should have its own meta tag like

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/abc" />
```

How can i do this? OR can i change meta tag dynamically??????

Comment: Try my answer i have also used that for my facebook application..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass that value from each or view action in ViewBag like below...

```
ViewBag.OgURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/abc";
```

then in you layout.cshtml

```
@ViewBag.OgURL
```

or set above head tag in you layout.cshtml..

```
@RenderSection("head", false)
```

and add in your view...

```
@section head {
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/abc" />
}
```