# asp.net URL rewriting Help required

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am working on a website,i am using URL rewritter(http://urlrewriter.net) i am using .net framework 3.5 and IIS 7,
I have to display details of user 
Currently i have a folder in my project named user with a Default.aspx file which rewrites URL like:

http://localhost:5000/user/123.aspx

where 123 is the UserID of the user i want to make it like

http://localhost:5000/user/123/Nameofuser.aspx

is it possible with using url rewritter?? ie the URL should like
http://localhost:5000/user/UserID/Nameofuser.aspx

Comment: Then i think this guy is still waiting for a response : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256892/mvc3-meta-tag-dynamically-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been quite a while since I've used url rewriter, but yes that should be possible.

Are you using 3.5 sp1?  sp1 made routing available to asp.net web forms.  Since 3.5 sp1 I've only used routing as it ships with .net and is used in mvc.  Tons of people use it so its easy to get support via sites like SO.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx